# Having trouble executing Python program in PHP

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I have an Apache web server where I display some graphs in my index.php page, however, these are updated frequently and I use a python program to do it, so I want to be able to run this python file every time my page is refreshed or loaded. I'm trying to use the `exec` function in php, but it doesn't seem to be executing the python file. This is the way I'm using the function:

```
<?php
    exec('sudo /usr/bin/python3 ttp.py');
```

I have this php script at the top of my index.php page.